# Url.openConnection() is throwing ProtocolException

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-networking

I'm trying to request a url which contains my app config. Requesting the url on a desktop is working. However, when trying to make the request in my Android app, I'm getting the following error.

```
W/System.err: java.net.ProtocolException: Too many follow-up requests: 21
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:417)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
...
```

I tried to request the same link with `Http` protocol and got a different error

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www-dev...
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
W/System.err:     at .networking.ResourceLoaderTask$override.doInBackground(ResourceLoaderTask.java:45)
W/System.err:     at .networking.ResourceLoaderTask$override.access$dispatch(ResourceLoaderTask.java)
W/System.err:     at .networking.ResourceLoaderTask.doInBackground(ResourceLoaderTask.java:0)
W/System.err:     at .networking.ResourceLoaderTask.doInBackground(ResourceLoaderTask.java:19)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
...
```

In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setInstanceFollowRedirects(boolean)) it says that I can disable redirects, but the problem is that the redirection is a must in my case. Even when requesting the Url in my browser it is redirecting to a new link.

My AsyncTask#doInBackground is like the folloing

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection ucon = null;
        try {
            String uri = params[0];                
            url = new URL(NetworkUtil.wrapURL(uri));
            ucon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            ucon.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", params[1]);        
            logUrl(ucon, url);   
            InputStream input = ucon.getInputStream();

            java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\A");
            String resource = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
            ucon.disconnect();

            return resource;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            ucon.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Did you find any solution ?